# Calculate business hours in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I calculate business hours between two date and times? For example we have two dates; 2022-01-21 16:35:02.470 and 2022-01-24 09:15:02.293

The working hours are 08:00 to 19:00 on weekdays

How can I calculate working hours with SQL?

Comment: Does it _have_ to be done in SQL? Date (and time) math in SQL can get ugly - it may be easier (and cleaner) in the app/service/form/report/whatever.

Comment: In your example, are you expecting 3 outcomes? (Friday 16:35 to 19:00, Saturday 08:00 to 13:00 and Monday 08:00 to 9:15)? Or rather, are you calculating the SUM of those 3 outcomes? An example outcome would be helpful.

Comment: yes it needs to be done in SQL. No i'm not expecting 3 outcomes, only one. the total work hours between 2 dates

Comment: So what is the expected result based on your sample dates?

Comment: You could do it with a stored proc and an ugly cursor.  Define a temp table in the proc defining the beginning/ending working hours for each day of the week.  Iterate over the days from the starting datetime and the ending datetime parameters.  Sum up the hours per day, with some logic for when the starting/ending datetime falls during the working hours for a day.

Comment: Don’t forget about holidays, Daylight Saving Time, etc.

Comment: Are these two dates on the same row (Ie FROM_DATE, TO_DATE), or on separate rows? The SQL will be very different. The best way is to dynamically generate a calendar of working dates (row for each day between the two dates), join to it finding overlaps. Some knowledge of your data would help here: for example, if the maximum days between FROM_DATE and TO_DATE is in the order of 10s (as opposed to 1000s) we can use recursive CTE to generate the calendar)

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the FROM and TO dates are on the same row:

```
With Tbl as (
    select FROM_DATE=cast('2022-01-21 16:35:02.470' as datetime),
           TO_DATE=cast('2022-01-24 09:15:02.293' as datetime)
           ),
--Build a calendar between two dates
Cal as (
    select DATE_D=cast(FROM_DATE as date), TO_DATE_D=cast(TO_DATE as date)
    from Tbl
    union all
    select DATE_D=dateadd(day,1,Cal.DATE_D), Cal.TO_DATE_D
    from Cal 
    where Cal.DATE_D<=Cal.TO_DATE_D
    ),
-- Eliminate weekends and non-working hours in the calendar
WorkDays as (
   select WDCAL_FROM_DATE=dateadd(hour, 8, cast(DATE_D as datetime)),
          WDCAL_TO_DATE=dateadd(hour, 19, cast(DATE_D as datetime))
   from Cal
   where datediff(day, '1900-01-06', DATE_D) % 7 not in (0,1) -- Saturdays, and Sundays
)
-- Find overlapping intervals, and calculate seconds in between, aggregate and convert to hours.
select 
    Hrs=sum(
         datediff(second, 
                case when T.FROM_DATE>=WD.WDCAL_FROM_DATE then T.FROM_DATE else WD.WDCAL_FROM_DATE end, -- Final interval FromDT
                case when T.TO_DATE<=WD.WDCAL_TO_DATE then T.TO_DATE else WD.WDCAL_TO_DATE end          -- Final interval ToDT
                )
           ) / 3600.
from Tbl T
     inner join
     WorkDays WD
     on T.FROM_DATE<=WD.WDCAL_TO_DATE
     and WD.WDCAL_FROM_DATE<=T.TO_DATE
```

gives number of hours, as a decimal fraction, within working hours.

If you need to take public holidays into account, I suggest that you first build a calendar table (instead of dynamically generating it).

Comment: Perfect ! its exactly what i need. Thank you so much

Comment: @SQLLearner if this worked for you, please mark as accepted answer and upvote.